# Bash script syntax error: operand expected when using pgrep directly on if condition

Tags: bash, shell, sh

My script `myscript.sh` checks if mysqld is running:

```
mypid=`pgrep mysqld`

if ! (( $mypid > 0 )); then
  echo "no"
else
  echo "yes"
fi
```

Output (running ./myscript.sh as root):

> yes

Now if I change the first line to a process that is not running e.g. `mysqld123`:

```
mypid=`pgrep mysqld123`

if ! (( $mypid > 0 )); then
  echo "no"
else
  echo "yes"
fi
```

Output:

> ./myscript.sh: line 3: ((: > 0 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 0 ")
>
> no

Expected output: `no` (without any errors)

So why does changing the process to something that is not running cause a syntax error, how can I resolve it?

Comment: Apparently, `pgrep` isn't producing any output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic of this comparison is entirely wrong. You expected if the pid is not available the operator `((..))` would fail and the negation logic would make your result a boolean True. That's *not* the case happening.

When the `pgrep` fails to match the process of the given name, it returns an empty result, so your comparison is literally becoming after expanding `pgrep mysqld123`

```
! ((   > 0  ))
```

with the LHS of the `>` being empty which is a syntax error for the `((..))` as it needs two operands to perform the arithmetic. The ideal logic would have been to use the return code of the `pgrep` command to the shell when it finds a match or when it fails to find a match as

```
if ! pgrep mysqld 2>&1 > /dev/null; then
    printf '%s\n' 'msqld not running'
fi
```

See [Arithmetic Expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) in `bash` for more relevant details on the subject. To answer to OP's question why quoting a variable inside `((..))` wouldn't work? - The `((..))` syntax is an arithmetic operator unlike `[` or `[[` which can handle empty strings if quoted properly. An empty value doesn't make sense in an arithmetic context, as if asking result of  `"" + 0`

Comment: I see, thank you. Can I check if the result is empty like so: `if [ -z "$mypid" ]; then echo "not running" fi` or would that be bad? I tried it and it works as far as I can tell

Comment: @RandomCoder: You can do that, as long as you quote the variable `mypid` properly as you've shown. But you can get rid of the use of a variable altogether if you follow my approach

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I like the variable because I can use it in logging, like `echo "found it running, PID is $mypid"`

Comment: Why can't I simply use quotes in my original comparison like `if ! (( "$mypid" > 0 )); `? Wouldn't that make it resolve to `! (( ""  > 0  ))`?

Comment: @RandomCoder: The `(( ))` syntax is an arithmetic operator unlike `[` or `[[` which can handle empty strings if quoted properly. An empty value doesn't make sense in an arithmetic context would it? Can you imagine asking `"" + 0`?

Comment: Many beginners seem to think their life will be easier somehow if there are some brackets after `if`.  This is not C, you will be fine, you won't be better off by making things more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: @tripleee are you saying I can omit some brackets to simplify?

Comment: I'm saying `if pid=$(pgrep thing)` is better than `pid=$(pgrep thing); if $pid ...` or the arithmetic evaluation you were trying to use.